# Wso2 EI 6.1.1 + third party rest api integration

Tags: rest, api, wso2

I'm unable to call third party rest api(https://api.github.com/users/hackeryou) in wso2 ei and wso2 esb.
Below is the sample code:

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="VerifyCustID" context="/mambu">
<resource methods="GET" uri-template="/verify">
<inSequence>
<log>
<property name="CustID API" value="*********Inside CustID API********** "/>
</log>
<send>
<endpoint>
<http method="GET" uri-template="https://api.github.com/users/hackeryou"/>
</endpoint>
</send>
</inSequence>
<outSequence>
<send/>
</outSequence>
</resource>
</api>
```

Below is the error in server log:

```
ID API = *********Inside CustID API**********
[2017-07-14 15:01:48,756] []  WARN - ConnectCallback Connection refused or failed for : api.github.com/192.30.253.116:443
[2017-07-14 15:01:48,759] []  WARN - EndpointContext Endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint with address https://api.github.com/users/hackeryou will be marked S
USPENDED as it failed
[2017-07-14 15:01:48,760] []  WARN - EndpointContext Suspending endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint with address https://api.github.com/users/hackeryou - cur
rent suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Fri Jul 14 15:02:18 IST 2017
[2017-07-14 15:01:48,772] []  INFO - LogMediator To: https://api.github.com/users/hackeryou, MessageID: urn:uuid:7b834e0e-e348-4b60-adeb-f60a70f00483,
 Direction: request, MESSAGE = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 101503, ERROR_MESSAGE = Error connecting to the back end, Envelope: <?
xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have some network connectivity issue to `api.github.com:443` (perhaps firewalls etc.)

The API worked fine for me on EI611:

[image]

If you are not using the **default** truststore (`client-truststore.jks`) that comes with WSO2 or have made changes to it, you **might** need to import the certificate for `api.github.com` into the trust store that your WSO2 server is actually using. 
Apart from network connectivity and missing certificate in trust store, can't see why your API shouldn't be able to call the remote service

Comment: Thank you so much Vijay.

Comment: @RajuK what was the issue finally ?

Comment: firewall issue, my firewall is not allowing to hit any third party api and this issue is resolved by network team.